# Getting mapQuest error: map.addControl is not a function

Tags: mapquest

I've loaded the MapQuest JavaScript api module and am able to bring in the basic sample map at http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/basic-map but when I try to add map controls using their next example I get the JavaScript error:

```
                            map.addControl is not a function
```

I tried window.map.addControl but that generates the same error.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try like this `map.current.addControl`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the map control code within your `MQA.EventUtil.observe`
right after your call to  `window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);`

### Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.0.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=Kmjtd%7Cluua2qu7n9%2C7a%3Do5-lzbgq"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', function() {

        /*Create an object for options*/
        var options={
          elt:document.getElementById('map'),        /*ID of element on the page where you want the map added*/
          zoom:10,                                   /*initial zoom level of map*/
          latLng:{lat:39.743943, lng:-105.020089},   /*center of map in latitude/longitude*/
          mtype:'map'                                /*map type (map)*/
        };

        /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/
        window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);
                                MQA.withModule('largezoom','traffictoggle','viewoptions','mousewheel', function() {

          map.addControl(
            new MQA.LargeZoom(),
            new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_LEFT, new MQA.Size(5,5))
          );

          map.addControl(new MQA.TrafficToggle());

          map.addControl(new MQA.ViewOptions());

          map.enableMouseWheelZoom();
        });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='map' style='width:750px; height:280px;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you [add the module](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.0/controls) for the control before adding the control to the map.

Comment: link only answers are generally invalid. Notice that your link has expired.

Comment: It expired just like the sdk being used.